# Who are these characters shown in "Spider-Man: Far From Home" trailer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, spider-man-far-from-home

In the recently released *Spider-Man: Far from Home* [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nt9L1jCKGnE) there are some new unknown characters. I already know there is:

> Mysterio

but who are the others?

[image: Character looking like Spider-Man in a black suit]

[image: Character wielding fire]

[image: Character seemingly composed of water]

[image: Sandman-like character]

Are these characters mentioned in comics? What are their names?

Comment: The first is Spiderman in his "stealth suit". Given Mysterio's nature, I suspect that the rest of these are illusions he's creating to play the hero.

Comment: Useful: https://www.thewrap.com/spider-man-far-from-home-jake-gyllenhaal-mysterio-elementals-water-monster-trailer/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be as complete as possible here these characters are:

#### Night Monkey

This is actually Peter in a new stealth suit given to him by "Nick Fury" so he can operate as Spider-Man in Europe without being recognised. At one point he was nearly recognised but Ned nicknamed him Spider Monkey, a European copycat, to cover up for him. This name then stuck and various news outlets picked it up and ran with the name.

#### The Elementals

The other three are four of the Elementals that all appear in the film. Here we have Molten-Man, Hydro-Man and Sandman. The fourth that you haven't included is Cyclone.

[image: Cyclone]

It is worth noting though that the Elementals are actually

> fake and are illusions created by Mysterio to further his own cause.

Answer (score 15):

The first image is Spider-Man in an alternate costume. The others are all members of a group called [the Elementals](https://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Elementals_(Earth-616)), a fairly obscure group of supervillains. If they use the same names as in the comics they would be Hellfire, Hydron, and Magnum respectively.

Answer (score 6):

The first one is:

> Night Monkey, a secret identity Spider-Man obtains by wearing a stealth suit while working with "Nick Fury" (Talos) in Europe. The suit itself is given to him by Talos (As Nick Fury of course).

The rest of the characters are Elementals but,

> They are in reality illusions created by Mysterio and his allies.